# Animation for CSS Flex changes based on content height

Tags: css, flexbox, css-animations

I'm looking for a way to animate Flex container height changes when sibling container's content is updated.

Below is a very simple example of a flex container. Please try clicking a button toggleText to see it in action. Is there any way to animate red container's height after sibling changes? I tried doing transition for flex but it doesn't work in my scenario.

Thanks!

```js
var i = 0;

var toggleText = function() {
  document.querySelector('p').innerHTML = text[(i++) % 2];
}


var text = [
  "Some short text here.",
  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."]
```

```css
.container {
  height: 140px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

.image {
  background-color: bisque;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggleText()">toggleText</button>

<div class="container">
  <p></p>
  <div class="image"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few limited ways to do this. The following idea came to my mind. I hope it works for you. I wish conveniences.

```js
var i = 0,
    hidden = document.querySelector('#hidden p'),
    visible = document.querySelector('#visible p'),
    hiddenHeight = 0,
    content;

var toggleText = function() {
  content = text[(i++) % 2];
  hidden.innerHTML = content;
  hiddenHeight = hidden.offsetHeight;
  hidden.innerHTML = "";
  visible.style.height = hiddenHeight+"px";
  visible.innerHTML = content;
}


var text = [
  "Some short text here.",
  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."]
```

```css
.container {
  height: 140px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  transition: all 500ms;
}

.container p{
  transition: all 500ms;
}

.image {
  background-color: bisque;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#hidden {
  height:0!important;
  overflow:hidden!important;
}
#hidden p{
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 500ms;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggleText()">toggleText</button>

<div class="container">
  <div id="hidden">
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div id="visible">
    <p style="height:0"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="image"></div>
</div>
```

You can change the [animation time and delays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions#Defining_transitions) as you like.